# remove / hide phpmyadmin from public url in openshift

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, openshift

We are struggling a lot with openshift and we are unable to remove / hide phpmyadmin from the public access, even though it is password protected.

We would like to remove / hide it, I found [this tutorial](http://www.thetechrepo.com/main-articles/488-change-default-access-url-of-phpmyadmin) which is closest to what we want but unable to do that as there is no `apache.conf` file.

Comment: what? didn't understand

Comment: @runningmark - I believe what Drew is trying to say is to abandon openshift and host your site directly on Amazon Web Services (AWS) EC2, as this is the underlying platform of openshift.

Comment: they are both great, just goofing around. IaaS and PaaS provide distinct advantages over one another depending on the audience

Answer (score 1):

try to add this in .htaccess file,

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from 121.134.56.1
```

where put your server ip for 121.134.56.18